# How to Warp the GridView into Carousel in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout, carousel

is it possible to put the GridView into Carousel in flutter like this??

i don't understand about the carousel but i learn it and i get the Carousel more useful then grid-view if i follow my design?

this is my GridView Code

```
Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    child: new StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 12,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                        itemCount: imageList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                              child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                                placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                                image: imageList[index],
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                          return new StaggeredTile.count(
                              1, index.isEven ? 1 : 2);
                        }),
                  )
```

[image]

Comment: can you include your `imageList[index]` and seems there is no issue on UI side but you are having different issue could be imagepath

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it was upload failed i need to re-upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can  simply use `StaggeredGridView` inside `CarouselSlider`. About the UI you are trying to archive, the first image(index=0) will be the large one. If we try to simplify the UI by dividing the pattern, we can see there are three GridItem can think as single bloc, and to get the left one larger we need to use `StaggeredTile.count(1, index % 3 == 0 ? 2 : 1);`. In this case `staggeredTileBuilder` will be

```dart
 staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
              return StaggeredTile.count(1, index % 3 == 0 ? 2 : 1);
            }),
```

[image]

**Widget**

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: CarouselSlider(
        items: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
            child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // it can use scollable if upper widget dont cause any issue
                shrinkWrap: true,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 12,
                mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                itemCount: imageList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.amber,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(index.toString()),
                        )
                        // FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                        //   // placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                        //   image: imageList[index],
                        //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        // ),
                        ),
                  );
                },
                staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                  return StaggeredTile.count(1, index % 3 == 0 ? 2 : 1);
                }),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
          ),
        ],
        options: CarouselOptions(aspectRatio: 1, viewportFraction: 1),
      ),
    );
```

I would say practice with Text Widget with viewing index to understand what and how widget is changing and set the logic inside `staggeredTileBuilder` to get the outcome. And about the imagePath you  aren't passing string value on that, debug/print the path to verify it.

For more about

- [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)
- [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)
- [Staggered Grid View on yt](https://youtu.be/h0H2t7fOGU4) you can find many by searching

Comment: Many thank brother, the knowledge that you give me i'm too glad too see this :> about my picture is upload failed so it can't show up, thank you for teaching me.

Comment: Glad to help you out.